# How can I make it set a value of paragraph in html in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a code I wrote in C#:

```
using (TcpClient whois = new TcpClient())
{
    try{
            whois.Connect(whoisServer, port);
            string domenpoziv = tipDomena + " " + domenIme + Environment.NewLine;

            byte[] domenpozivBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(domenpoziv.ToCharArray());
            Stream whoIsStream = whois.GetStream();
            whoIsStream.Write(domenpozivBytes, 0, domenpozivBytes.Length);

            StreamReader whoIsStreamReader = new StreamReader(whois.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            string streamoutput = "";
            List<string> whoIsInfo = new List<string>();
            while (null != (streamoutput = whoIsStreamReader.ReadLine()))
            {
                whoIsInfo.Add(streamoutput);
            }

            whois.Close();
            return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, whoIsInfo);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            // Handle network errors
            return $"Error connecting to WHOIS server: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried implementing into a JavaScript function and expected it to output into the HTML paragraph and it didn't work, giving me `WebSocket` error.

Comment: What do you mean you tried "implementing into a JavaScript function" ?